# What is the best Python way to represent next line of code?

Tags: python, indentation, pep8

The basic idea was to write a line like this:

```py
url = 'https://{host}?key={key}&lang={lang}&text='.format(**data)  + '&text='.join(words)
```

Wanted to rewrite it with PEP 8 Style, so wrote this:

```py
url = 'https://{host}?key={key}&lang={lang}&text='.format(**data) \
    + '&text='.join(words)
```

What one of those is right?

If neither, I would like to hear why, and see how would you write it.

Comment: PEP8 is not a religion, either is readable to me

Comment: I'd recommend just turning on an autoformatter like the vscode setting or black and just letting that handle these questions for you

Comment: I was about to write "My preference would be to write ..." and realized that this question is very much "primarily opinion based".

Comment: If you use the `requests` library, you can do something like `requests.get(f'https://{data.host}', params={'key': data.key, 'lang': data.lang, 'text': words})`.

Comment: @0x5453, thanks, didn't know I can use dict's keys in string like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urlencode` function can handle this case -- even with your list of words:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

host = 'example.com'
data = {'key': 'asdf', 'lang': 'en-us', 'text': ['sam', 'i', 'am']}
params = urlencode(data, True)
url2 = 'https://{host}?' + params
```

This will produce: `https://example.com?key=asdf&lang=en-us&text=sam&text=i&text=am`

Note that `urlencode` is called with `doseq` parameter set to `True` to handle your list of repetitive parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Neither? I'd probably be tempted to go for the methods designed for this, eg:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

host = 'example.com'
data = {'key': 'foo', 'lang': 'bar', 'text': 'baz'}
url = 'https://{host}?{query}'.format(host=host, query=urlencode(data))
```

That'll give you a `url` of:

```
'https://example.com?key=foo&lang=bar&text=baz'
```

Comment: Note that if `words` was a list (from the OP) you may need to pass a flag in the call to urlencode: `query=urlencode(data, True)`

Comment: It's good, but it doesn't quite fit in my case. I got a list of words that has more than one word, so I have to use more than one 'text' key in url

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Python Style Guide](http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/contributing/en/latest/cross-project-policies/python-style-guide.html#maximum-line-length), the maximum length for a line should be 79 characters but “for flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.”

However when writing code it comes to personal taste how to really format code, some people won't be bothered with lines larger than 79 characters(even though is appreciated to stick to that for readiness purposes) and others may like lines shorter than 79 characters.